# O que é a propriedade "groups" no resultado de uma RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

Quando se busca uma determinada ocorrência numa string com RegEx sem a flag `g` (de *global*), o resultado vêm, além da array com a ocorrência encontrada, outras propriedades, como `index`, `input` e `groups`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
var string = "abc";
var re = string.match(/b/);
console.log("Ocorrência:", re);
console.log("Index:", re.index);
console.log("Input:", re.input);
console.log("Groups:", re.groups);
```

Minha dúvida é: o que é e pra que serve essa propriedade `groups`?

Eu achava que seria algum grupo capturado, mas quando coloco o `b` dentro de parênteses para criar um grupo, mesmo assim a propriedade `groups` retorna `undefined`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
var string = "abc";
var re = string.match(/(b)/);
console.log("Ocorrência:", re);
console.log("Index:", re.index);
console.log("Input:", re.input);
console.log("Groups:", re.groups);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), a propriedade `groups` contém os ***named** capturing groups* ([grupos de captura com nome](https://regular-expressions.info/named.html)):

> An array of named capturing groups or `undefined` if no named capturing groups were defined.

Em tradução livre:

> Um array de grupos de captura com nome ou `undefined` se nenhum grupo de captura com nome estiver definido.

Um grupo de captura simples (com somente parênteses) não tem nome, por isso não é retornado em `groups`. Para ter um grupo com nome, basta usar `(?<Nome>`:

```js
var string = "abc";
var re = string.match(/(?<letra>b)/);
console.log("Ocorrência:", re);
console.log("Index:", re.index);
console.log("Input:", re.input);
console.log("Groups:", re.groups);
```

No caso acima, o grupo se chama "letra", e o seu valor é a letra "b".

---

Lembrando que *named capturing groups* é um recurso que [foi adicionado no ECMAScript 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367407).

Comment: Legal cara! Não sabia disso rs... valeu mesmo!

Comment: @Sam O nome da propriedade confunde, né? A primeira vez que vi, tb achei que ela tinha todos os grupos...

Comment: Sim, eu achei isso tb rs...

Comment: Boa resposta!! Acho que poderia adicionar que esse recurso de grupos nas expressões regulares é de uma versão mais recente do JavaScript. Se não me engano, ES2018!

Comment: @LuizFelipe Eu estava procurando um link com a versão exata. Resposta atualizada, obrigado! :-)