# O que é RegExp Match Indices?

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Recentemente encontrei [este pacote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regexp-match-indices), que serve de *polyfill* para um novo recurso do JavaScript. A proposta [RegExp Match Indices](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-match-indices) foi finalizada recentemente, o que significa que em breve fará parte da linguagem.

Na página do *polyfill* no npm, consta o seguinte:

> A implementação é uma substituição para `RegExp.prototype.exec` que se aproxima do comportamento da proposta. Como `RegExp.prototype.exec` depende de um receptor (o valor deste), a exportação principal aceita a RegExp para operar como o primeiro argumento.

Ele ainda demonstra um código de exemplo (*Polyfill*):

```js
const execWithIndices = require('regexp-match-indices');

const text = 'zabbcdef';
const re = new RegExp('ab*(cd(?<Z>ef)?)');
const result = execWithIndices(re, text);
console.log(result.indices); // [[1, 8], [4, 8], [6, 8]]
```

O resultado acima (`console.log`), é muito confuso para minha pessoa, pois não tenho um conhecimento decente sobre expressões regulares.

As coisas ficaram mais confusas quando li a documentacão da proposta no GitHub e analisei o código que simula a [implementacão real](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-match-indices#examples):

```js
const re1 = /a+(?<Z>z)?/d;

// indices are relative to start of the input string:
const s1 = 'xaaaz';
const m1 = re1.exec(s1);
m1.indices[0][0] === 1;
m1.indices[0][1] === 5;
s1.slice(...m1.indices[0]) === 'aaaz';

m1.indices[1][0] === 4;
m1.indices[1][1] === 5;
s1.slice(...m1.indices[1]) === 'z';

m1.indices.groups['Z'][0] === 4;
m1.indices.groups['Z'][1] === 5;
s1.slice(...m1.indices.groups['Z']) === 'z';

// capture groups that are not matched return `undefined`:
const m2 = re1.exec('xaaay');
m2.indices[1] === undefined;
m2.indices.groups['Z'] === undefined;
```

Na implementacão oficial (código acima), ele faz o uso de uma flag `d`, mas esta ainda não consta, até o presente momento desta pergunta, na documentacão da [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

<sup>**1**</sup> Pelo que eu entendi, esta flag `d` cria uma propriedade `indices` **e retorna os indices das capturas**, mas não tenho certeza. Exemplificando, usando sem a flag `d`, temos o objeto:

```js
const re1 = /a+(?<Z>z)?/;

const s1 = "xaaaz";
const m1 = re1.exec(s1)

console.log(m1)

// saida
// (2) ["aaaz", "z", index: 1, input: "xaaaz", groups: {…}]
//  0: "aaaz"
//  1: "z"
//  groups: {Z: "z"}
//  index: 1
//  input: "xaaaz"
//  length: 2
//  __proto__: Array(0)
```

<sup>O output acima não aparece no snippet do SO.</sup>

No código do NPM, eu executei o script e semelhante ao da documentacão (com o *Polyfill* claro) para analisar e comparar o comportamento do uso da flag `d`. Este retorna "basicamente" a mesma coisa:

```js
const execWithIndices = require("regexp-match-indices");

const text = "xaaaz";
const re = new RegExp("a+(?<Z>z)?");
const result = execWithIndices(re, text);

console.log(result)

// saida
// [
//   'aaaz',
//   'z',
//   index: 1,
//   input: 'xaaaz',
//   groups: [Object: null prototype] { Z: 'z' },
//   indices: [Getter/Setter]
// ]
```

Só que agora, ele vem com essa propriedade `indices` que representam o onde foi feito o *match* do grupo de captura (eu acho), por isso da minha afirmacão (<sup>**`1`**</sup>).

Gostaria de saber mais do proposito desta nova flag `d`, desta funcionalidade, de uma explicacão de caso de uso e, de preferência, uma explicacão sobre o uso no código acima.

<sub><sub>`(?<Z>z)` é um grupo de captura, certo?</sub></sub>

Comment: Sim, `(?<Z>z)` é um [grupo de captura nomeado](https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-named-capture-groups.html#named-capture-groups). Embora a sintaxe possa parecer "difícil", o `<Z>` apenas indica o nome do grupo, que, nesse caso, é `Z`. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ideia da [proposta](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-match-indices) é retornar o índice inicial e final do *match* encontrado, e também dos grupos de captura, quando presentes.

Antes desta proposta, ao usar [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) ou [`String.prototype.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), o máximo que tínhamos era o índice inicial em que o *match* é encontrado. Ou seja, neste código:

```js
const s1 = 'zabbcdef';
const m1 = s1.match(/ab*(cd(?<Z>ef)?)/);
for (const e in m1) {
    console.log(e, m1[e]);
}
```

O resultado (o array `m1`) possui uma propriedade `index`, que indica o índice no qual o *match* se inicia (no caso, é `1`, a posição da string onde está o `a`). Ele também tem a [propriedade `groups`, que contém os *named groups*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/383614/112052) (um [grupo nomeado](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) - no caso, é o `(?<Z>ef)`, que indica que o conteúdo `ef` faz parte do grupo cujo nome é "Z").

No array `m1` também são retornados os próprios grupos de captura (`cdef` e `ef`), mas não há informação sobre os seus índices.

---

A ideia da proposta é ter os índices inicial e final do *match* todo e também de cada grupo de captura. No caso da regex acima, temos 2 grupos:

- `(?<Z>ef)` é um grupo nomeado (seu nome é "Z", o conteúdo é `ef`)
- `(cd(?<Z>ef)?)` é um grupo sem nome, seu conteúdo é `cd` seguido do conteúdo do grupo "Z" (e todo o grupo "Z" é opcional, pois tem o `?` logo depois)

No caso, os grupos são "numerados" na ordem em que aparecem: o grupo que tem `cd etc...` é o primeiro, e o grupo nomeado é o segundo.

Enfim, os índices retornados no exemplo do *polyfill* são:

- `[ 1, 8 ]`: onde começa o *match* todo, pois `1` é a posição onde está o `a` que inicia a regex, e `8` é uma posição depois de onde o *match* termina - no caso, é onde está o `f`
- `[ 4, 8 ]`: o grupo sem nome começa no índice 4 - é aí que está o `c` na string, é aí que começa o *sub-match* referente a este grupo
- `[ 6, 8 ]`: `6` é o índice onde se encontra o `e`, é aí que começa o *sub-match* referente ao grupo.

E quando há um grupo nomeado, os seus índices também são colocados em `indices.groups`, na forma de um objeto, no qual as chaves são os nomes dos grupos e os valores são os respectivos índices.

---

Como o grupo nomeado é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (indicado pelo `?`), se a string fosse `zabbcd123`, o último grupo de índices (`[6, 8]`) não seria retornado (no seu lugar, é colocado `undefined`).

Segundo a proposta, a propriedade `indices` só seria retornada se a regex tiver a *flag* `d`. Ou seja, a regex seria criada como `/ab*(cd(?<Z>ef)?)/d` ou `new RegExp('ab*(cd(?<Z>ef)?)', 'd')`.

Recentemente (maio/2021) a MDN atualizou a documentação, e lá já consta a *flag* `d`: veja [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags). É interessante notar também que toda instância de `RegExp` passará a ter a [propriedade `hasIndices`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/hasIndices), indicando se a *flag* `d` foi usada (`true` ou `false`). **Mas não deixe de consultar a [tabela de compatibilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/hasIndices#browser_compatibility) antes de sair usando**, pois ainda não são todos os browsers que suportam.

Portanto, o código abaixo pode ou não funcionar no seu browser (testei no Chrome 90 e foi):

```js
// maio/2021 - só funciona em alguns browsers (testado no Chrome 90)
var r = /ab*(cd(?<Z>ef)?)/d; // regex com a flag d
console.log('tem a flag:', r.hasIndices); // true

var result = 'zabbcdef'.match(r);
console.log('índices:', result.indices);
console.log('índices dos grupos:', result.indices.groups);
```

---

Apenas para tentar esclarecer um pouco mais, segue outro exemplo:

```
const execWithIndices = require("regexp-match-indices");
const text = "- abc 123 xy 4567 .";
const result = execWithIndices(/([a-z]+) (?<nums>\d+) ([a-z]+) (?<othernums>\d+)/, text);
console.log(result.indices);
```

A regex busca por sequências de letras (`[a-z]+`) e números (`\d+`), sendo que os números estão em grupos nomeados, e as letras estão em grupos "normais" (sem nome).

Para ser mais preciso, a regex busca por letras, espaço, números, espaço, letras, espaço e números. Há quatro grupos de captura: o primeiro e o terceiro buscam pelas letras, e o segundo e quarto buscam pelos números (e estes possuem os nomes "nums" e "othernums").

Neste caso, o valor da propriedade `indices` é o array:

```
[
  [ 2, 17 ],
  [ 2, 5 ],
  [ 6, 9 ],
  [ 10, 12 ],
  [ 13, 17 ],
  groups: { nums: [ 6, 9 ], othernums: [ 13, 17 ] }
]
```

No caso, os elementos do array são:

- `[2, 17]`: os índices que correspondem a todo o *match* encontrado (ou seja, corresponde a todo o trecho "abc 123 xy 4567")
- `[2, 5]`: os índices que correspondem ao primeiro grupo de captura (a primeira ocorrência de "uma ou mais letras" - o trecho "abc")
- `[6, 9]`: os índices que correspondem ao segundo grupo de captura (a primeira ocorrência de "um ou mais dígitos" - o trecho "123")
- `[10, 12]`: os índices que correspondem ao terceiro grupo de captura (a segunda ocorrência de "uma ou mais letras" - o trecho "xy")
- `[13, 17]`: os índices que correspondem ao quarto grupo de captura (a segunda ocorrência de "um ou mais dígitos" - o trecho "4567")
- a propriedade `groups`, que é um objeto contendo os índices correspondentes aos grupos nomeados (sendo que o nome de cada grupo é uma chave, e o valor é o respectivo array contendo os índices)

Agora, se a segunda ocorrência das letras e dos números for opcional:

```
const execWithIndices = require("regexp-match-indices");
const text = "- abc 123.";
const result = execWithIndices(/([a-z]+) (?<nums>\d+)(?: ([a-z]+) (?<othernums>\d+))?/, text);
console.log(result.indices);
```

O resultado será:

```
[
  [ 2, 9 ],
  [ 2, 5 ],
  [ 6, 9 ],
  undefined,
  undefined,
  groups: { nums: [ 6, 9 ], othernums: undefined }
]
```

Ou seja, foi retornado `undefined` nas posições correspondentes aos grupos que estão presentes na regex, mas por estarem em uma parte que é opcional, acabaram não sendo preenchidos.

E claro, se a regex não tiver nenhum grupo de captura, só serão retornados os índices referentes ao *match* encontrado. Ou seja, no caso abaixo:

```
const execWithIndices = require("regexp-match-indices");
const text = "- abc 123 xy 4567 .";
const result = execWithIndices(/[a-z]+ \d+/, text);
console.log(result.indices);
```

O resultado será:

```
[ [ 2, 9 ], groups: undefined ]
```

Ou seja, os índices `[2, 9]` indicam onde começa e termina o *match* (que no caso são as letras, espaço e os números), e como não há grupos, não há mais elementos (e como não há grupos nomeados, a propriedade `groups` é `undefined`).

---

Vale lembrar que no pacote do npm a propriedade `indices` é por padrão *lazy*, e só é populada caso seja requisitada (ou seja, se você só usar `result` nos exemplos acima, o `result.indices` não estará populado, somente quando você acessa diretamente `result.indices` é que ele passa a ter o array com os índices). Este comportamento pode ser mudado para ficar igual ao da especificação, na qual não há o comportamento *lazy*, Veja a diferença:

```
const execWithIndices = require("regexp-match-indices");
const text = "- abc 123 xy 4567 .";
let result = execWithIndices(/[a-z]+ \d+/, text);
console.log(result); // mostra "indices: [Getter/Setter]"

// desativar o modo "lazy", deixar igual ao do especificação
require("regexp-match-indices/config").mode = "spec-compliant";
result = execWithIndices(/[a-z]+ \d+/, text);
console.log(result); // mostra "indices: [ [2, 9], groups: undefined ]"
```